# Magento 2 : Import product with external image URL

Tags: magento2, product-images, import, magento2.3.2, import-products

I have a CSV file with image field is external image URL, how can I import it, hope anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out of the box, but I found a bug when trying to run the import.
Normally, you just need to specify the URL of the image for the specific product in the CSV file.

You can check status of the bug here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24941